# Whether it is possible to change JavaFX datePicker to skip days?

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

My question is this: Is there a solution to bekome a DatePicker with only the month and year without days? Since a standard DatePuicker works with Java LocalDate it does not seems so simple...

One of the options is to make the text field with a mask through regex, but then the "Picker" would be lost, that I would like to leave. Has somebody already faced with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is what you need - http://myjavafx.blogspot.ru/2012/01/javafx-calendar-control.html